# on simplifying an expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions

After some integration process, I ended up with the following expression:

```
(1/(b (-1 + E^b) Re[b]))E^-Re[b](  b E^b - b + E^Re[b] Re[b] - E^(b + Re[b]) Re[b]
                                 + E^Re[b] Sqrt[E^(-2 b) (-1 + E^b)^2] Re[b]
                                 + b E^(b + Re[b]) Sqrt[E^(-2b)(-1 + E^b)^2] Re[b] )
```

all is good, but this expression is supposed to be equal to

```
1 + (2/b) e^(-b) - 1/b
```

via simple numerical trials, i can confirm that they are equal. But, it would be great if I can actually make *Mathematica* simplify that nasty expression into this innocent form.
I tried, `Fullsimplify`, it does not work. Does anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: Use `//ComplexExpand//PowerExpand//Simplify` (I suppose `b` is Real, if not, dont use the `ComplexExpand` part)

Comment: Using Simplify[PowerExpand[%]] worked. Thank you. I did not know that this was more powerful than FullSimplify. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Perhaps you should declare b as a real (using the option `Assumptions`) in your integration process. it might save you some time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Algebraic simplifications like `Simplify` and `FullSimplify` can be used with the second argument - assumptions. We can assume e.g. that b is a real number i.e. `b ∈ Reals` (otherwise the system assumes that `b` is complex) :

```
Simplify[ (1/(b (-1 + E^b) Re[b])) E^-Re[b](-b + b E^b + E^Re[b] Re[b]
           - E^(b + Re[b]) Re[b] + E^Re[b] Sqrt[E^(-2 b) (-1 + E^b)^2] Re[b]
           + b E^(b + Re[b]) Sqrt[E^(-2 b) (-1 + E^b)^2] Re[b]),  b ∈ Reals] // 
 TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Since there are two cases `b >= 0` and `b < 0` (in general there might be more cases depending on the assumptions) we should map `Expand` on the output ( common shorthands  `Map` -- `/@`  and  `MapAll` -- `//@`)

```
Expand //@ % // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

The same answer you can get with `FullSimplify`.

Comment: Thank you very much @ Artes. Much obliged!

Answer (score 6):

The expression you gave simplifies to the form you are looking for *only for positive and real $b$*.  Just give this assumption in `Simplify`:

```
In[14]:= Simplify[expr, b > 0]
Out[14]= (E^-b (2 + (-1 + b) E^b))/b

In[15]:= Expand[%]
Out[15]= 1 - 1/b + (2 E^-b)/b
```

Comment: thank you @ Szabolcs. You are absolutely right, b is real.