# Simplifying an exponential expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have an expression: 
(1/a^13)^(1/13)

I want Mathematica to simplify it to '1/a'. How do I do it? 'Simplify' and 'FullSimplify' don't work.

Answer (score 1):

Please be sure what you are doing! *Mathematica* always treats variables to be complex by default. Are the power laws correct in this general assumption? Here you can go with

```
PowerExpand[(1/a^13)^(1/13)]
```

but don't forget the warning in its documentation:

> The transformations made by PowerExpand are correct in general only if c is an integer or a and b are positive real numbers.

Comment: How do you make the text appear in gray?

Comment: You indent this line by 4 spaces. Please see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) for a detailed tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I got to know the answer at another page on this site [on simplifying an expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23258/on-simplifying-an-expression). The point is to make 'Assumptions' in Mathematica

So, the following works:

```
Simplify[(1/a^13)^(1/13), Assumptions -> a > 0]
```

Or one can declare Assumptions separately.